# count items by genre

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

i'm trying to count items by there genre in order to represent name & badge count but it look like im missing something 
my code like like this 
in my model :

```
  public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
```

viewModel :

```
   public IEnumerable<LectureGig> UpcomingLectureGigs { get; set; }
```

controller:

```
var upCommingLecture = _context.LectureGigs.Include(g => g.Artist).Include(g => g.Genre)
            .Where(g => (g.DateTime > DateTime.Now
                         && !g.IsCanceled ||
                         (g.IsWeekLy && (int) g.Days == (myDayOfWeek) || (int) g.Days >= 7)));

        var viewModel = new GigsViewModel
        {
            UpcomingLectureGigs = upCommingLecture.ToList().OrderBy(d => d.Days).ThenBy(g => g.GenreId),
            //remove for clear code
        };

        ViewBag.genre = viewModel.UpcomingLectureGigs.GroupBy(g => g.Genre.Name).Distinct();
```

and my view :

```
 @foreach (var gen in ViewBag.genre)
{
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">@gen.Name <span class="badge"></span></button>
}
```

the error i'm getting is :'string' does not contain a definition for 'Genre'
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thy this:

```
ViewBag.genres = viewModel.UpcomingLectureGigs.GroupBy(g=>g.Genre.Name).Select(g=> new KeyValuePair<string, int>(g.Key,g.Count())).ToList();


 @foreach (var g in ViewBag.genres)
        {
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">@g.Key<span class="badge">@g.Value
            </span></button>
        }
```

[Working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gIzoI5)

Comment: Take a look at the updated version. צריך להיות בסדר :-)